# Searching In Data in public spreadsheet using Javascript in HTML|

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

is there a way to search for data presented in google spreadsheet using javascript in HTML? i already publish my spreadsheet in public and founded a code that can generate table just like this.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var spData = null;
  function doData(json) {
      spData = json.feed.entry;
  }
  
  function drawCell(tr, val) {
      var td = $("<td/>");
      tr.append(td);
      td.append(val);
      return td;
  }
  function drawRow(table, rowData) {
      if (rowData == null) return null;
      if (rowData.length == 0) return null;
      var tr = $("<tr/>");
      table.append(tr);
      for(var c=0; c<rowData.length; c++) {
          drawCell(tr, rowData[c]);
      }
      return tr;
  }
  
  function drawTable(parent) {
      var table = $("<table/>");
      parent.append(table);
      return table;
  }
  
  function readData(parent) {
      var data = spData;
      var table = drawTable(parent);
      var rowData = [];
      
      for(var r=0; r<data.length; r++) {
          var cell = data[r]["gs$cell"];
          var val = cell["$t"];
          if (cell.col == 1) {
              drawRow(table, rowData);
              rowData = [];
          }
          rowData.push(val);
      }
      drawRow(table, rowData);
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
      readData($("#data"));
  });

  </script>   
<script src="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/1yP86XyIehWtks3mek0-BQd4zMF_ZrWcYDfSET8MNLhY/1/public/values?alt=json-in-script&callback=doData"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  table {border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}
  th, td {border: thin solid black; padding: 3px;}
  tr.head th, tr.head td {background-color: #EDEDED; border-bottom: 4px double black;}
  span.linetitle {font-weight: bold;}
  div.lineclass {font-style: italic;}
  .title, .result {width: 80%;}
  .notes {width: 15%;}
  h1 {text-align: center;}
  body {margin: 12px; font-size: 12px;}
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">
  form {display: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Parse Google Spreadsheet with JavaScript</h1> 
<div id="data"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I've read that API's can be used in order to done this but i dont have any background knowledge regarding to that complicated type of environment.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. What is the context of this script? What data do you plan on retrieving and how?

Comment: i have data in google spreadsheet, i've found out how to pull the data to my website but the script is not realtime. I dont know what triggers to put, I also tried to put set.Interval but when I put it, the data keeps looping and tables are generated over and over.